# java socket io server doesn't receives specific events from client

Tags: java, sockets, io, socket.io

I have a simple java project in IDEA, with simple socketio server based on com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer, and simple client. When i try to connect client to server it connects successfully which is prooved by logs. But when i try to send an event to server via socket.emit() nothing happens (by logs), however client can succesfully receive events from server, sent via server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent(). How can i send events from client to server? Realy need help with this, thanks!

Client impl:

```
package ru.cnv.application.core;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import ru.cnv.application.view.SampleViewverViewMessage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestClient {

    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:9092");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, args -> {
            SampleViewverViewMessage message = new SampleViewverViewMessage();
            message.setMessage("lol");
            System.out.println("connected");
            Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(aLong -> {
                socket.emit("message", message);
                System.out.println("try to send");
            });
        }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, args -> {
            System.out.println("not connected");
        }).on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, args -> {
            System.out.println("err");
        }).on("m", args -> {
            System.out.println("m");
        });

        socket.connect();
    }
}
```

Server impl:

```
package ru.cnv.framework.view;

import com.corundumstudio.socketio.*;
import ru.cnv.application.view.SampleViewverViewMessage;
import ru.cnv.library.utils.GsonUtils;
import ru.cnv.library.view.PresenterView;

public abstract class SocketView implements PresenterView {

    public SocketView() {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("localhost");
        config.setPort(9092);

        SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
        server.addEventListener("message", SampleViewverViewMessage.class, (client, data, ackRequest) -> {
            SampleViewverViewMessage message = new SampleViewverViewMessage();
            System.out.println(GsonUtils.objectToJson(message));
        });
        server.addConnectListener(client -> {
            System.out.println(GsonUtils.objectToJson("connected"));
            SampleViewverViewMessage message = new SampleViewverViewMessage();
            server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent("m", message);
        });

        server.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        server.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I have the same problem! Did you succeed to fix it?

Comment: Not, unfortunality, some mysterious trouble